# Only last item of array is replaced

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop, replace

I need to replace variables for the body of an email. If the name of the variables exists in the `variableNames` array, then it must be replaced.

But the problem is that only the last one that corresponds to the last name of the `variableNames` Names is replaced (in my case: `'NAME4'`). What am I doing wrong? How can I solve it?

```
var variableNames = [
  'NAME1',
  'NAME2',
  'NAME3',
  'NAME4'];

var regex = '';
var key2 = '';
var position = '';

for (var key in variables) {

  if (variableNames.includes(key)) {

    position = variableNames.indexOf(key);
    key2 = variableNames[position];
    regex = new RegExp("###" + key2 + "###", "g");

    template.content = template.body.replace(regex, variables[key2]); 
    //only replace the last one
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input string you're replacing is always `template.body` (so, after each iteration, only the original string, replaced *once*, is assigned to `template.content`).

Save the string you're replacing in a variable.

Also, because you're looking for the `key` in the `variableNames` array, and constructing the regex from that, an `includes` check is enough - just pass the `key` to `new RegExp`, no need to search the array again to acquire the variable you already have:

```
const variableNames = [
  'NAME1',
  'NAME2',
  'NAME3',
  'NAME4'
];

let tempString = template.body;
for (const key in variables) {
  if (variableNames.includes(key)) {
    const regex = new RegExp("###" + key + "###", "g");
    tempString = tempString.replace(regex, variables[key]);
  }
}
template.content = tempString;
```

This could probably be done even more elegantly with a replacer function, but it's hard to say what exactly the code would be like without knowing a bit more about `variables`.